# Good way to store data about u customers who visited w webpages on d days

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

This is interview question from Amazon.

Given `u` lists of customers who visited `w` webpages on `d` days, design a data structure to get customers who have visited the website on exactly `k` days and should have visited at least `m` distinct pages altogether.

Assume `u`, `w` and `d` are large numbers.

How do we store this information? Maybe we can use hash maps, trees, etc.

Comment: How can the number of days be large, given that WWW has been around for less than 8,500 days?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is the way interviewer asked such question .. cant say much about that

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Good point, but I suppose this is more of a theoretical question, testing the knowledge / potential of the interviewee. For the sake of practicality, we can probably generalize to hours / minutes or assume this data structure will be used for the next few thousand years.

Comment: Does "the website" mean "any given website"? And I suppose it's `n` customers, `o` webpages and `p` days (presumably different numbers - `n = n = n` while `n ?= o ?= p`).

Comment: @Dukeling yah correct.

Answer (score 4):

**Assumptions:**

We have queries which give some web page `j` and ask for a list of users that have visited the web pages on exactly `k` days and have visited at least `m` distinct pages in total.

For the below, assume "map" = "hashmap", which would, ideally, give constant time queries. One can also use "treemap" at a logarithmic cost i.t.o the number of elements. Similarly for "set", "hashset", "treeset".

I'm assuming the input isn't static, but I won't really change my approach if it is.

**Basic idea:**

- **For each user, have a map of web pages to counts and last visited day**. We can have a map of user identifiers to the map of web pages.
- Whenever a user visits a page:

  - If it's a new page, just create a map entry with the page to a count of 1 and the last visited day
  - otherwise, if the day is the same as the last visited day, do nothing,
  - otherwise, increment the count and update the last visited day.
  - Total time per update = `O(1)`
- For queries:

  - Loop through all users - `O(u)`
  - Look up the page for that user and check that the count matches - `O(1)`
  - Check that the count of the map is `>= m` - `O(1)`
  - Total time per query = `O(n)`

**Improvements:**

We can have a separate **map of web page to unique ID** (then obviously use the unique ID instead of the URL for the above map). It won't really change the complexity, but should improve both the space and time complexity by a constant factor.

At the cost of quite a bit of space, we can do the following (in addition to having the map from `Basic idea`):

- **For each web page, have an array of sets of user identifiers** where index `i` in the array is a set of all users that visited that page on exactly `i` days.
- Whenever a user visits a page:

  - Do the same as in `Basic idea`
  - Move the user from the current number of visits for that page to the new number of visits (or insert into the 1 visit set if new).
  - Total time per update = `O(1)`
- For queries:

  - We can find all users that visited any given page on exactly `k` days in `O(1)`.
  - From here we run through this smaller list of users (say there are `p` of them) and check the counts of the maps of each user (in `O(1)`).
  - Total time per query = `O(p)`

Feel free to point out if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward structure would be to emulate what an RDBMS would do:

**1.** Have an object that contains all the basic info: (Customer, Days-Count, Distinct-Pages-Count)

**2.** Then, add a Tree that functions as an index to this, using (Days-Count, Distinct-Pages-Count) as its key (B-tree, or something similar)

**3.** You could also have another index-type structure with key of Customer. That way, you can update the information quickly

**4.** Finally, you would need to have more detailed information to figure out whether a page being visted was unique. This would involve storing Distinct page information under the customer (not clear from the question if this means distinct on a particular day, or across all days)

Answer (score 1):

Implement using two hash maps:

1. `hash map<customerId,HashSet<webpages>>`
2. `hash map<customerId,HashSet<days>>`

If new customer id then create new hashset insert in it else put that day or webpage in hash set for existing customer.

For each customer id see set `length>=m` in first hash map and in second hash map set `length=k` output that customer.